How do I compute the Standard Error for summed percentages?
I feel profoundly stupid for having to ask this question--it feels like the answer should be obvious, or at the very least that it should be easy to find on the internet, but so far I have been unable to.
It's a pretty simple question: Say I have a dataset broken out by age group with the following N, percentages and Standard Errors. This is roughly analogous to an existing dataset I am working on--I have the age groups and Standard Errors already and they look something-ish like below.
n = 2000 (i.e. total sample size)



Age
Percent of Sample
Standard Error




18-29
11%
1.5%


30-39
14%
1.7%


40-49
32%
1.3%


50-59
23%
1.6%


60-69
12%
1.8%


70-79
8%
0.9%



I would like to combine age groups and compute the new standard errors so that the data looks something like this:



Age
Percent of Sample
Standard Error




18-39
25%
?.?%


40-59
55%
?.?%


60-79
20%
?.?%



I would like to know how to use the Percentages and Standard Errors in the first table to compute the missing Standard Errors in the second table.
I have found a lot of help for combining Standard Errors from separate samples--say, for example, if 15% of one sample is left handed and 20% of a second sample is left-handed. I have not found any help for combining Standard Errors within a distribution (adding together the 18-29 and 30-39 age groups and computing a new Standard Error for the combined total). As far as I know the math could be identical; I'm working on puzzling it out, but I have a time-sensitive project I'm working on right now that requires this type of combination so I need to lean on people who are more comfortable with this type of work than me. Any help you could offer in this regards would be immensely appreciated, even if it is just to say "This has already been answered, you fool!" along with some directions for where to find the answer.

To specify, in response to commenters -- the standard errors being referred to here are not for a separate variable. They are the standard errors of the proportion. So, for the Age 18-29 bracket, the percent of the sample would be 11% and the standard error of the percent would be 1.5%.


Without knowing rhe covariances it will be difficult.

This will depend on the variable or estimate for which you have the standard error values and what the percentage values for the standard errors mean. Are you just talking about the estimates of the proportion of the entire sample that are within each age group, or something else? Please edit the question to provide more background about the subject matter and the question that you are addressing.

@ EdM - Yes, I am talking about the estimates of the proportion of the entire sample that are within each age group. The standard errors apply to the estimates of the proportion.

Your table is not consistent with that interpretation, because the SE for a proportion $p$ within a sample of size $n$ is $\sqrt{p(1-p)/n}.$  How, then, do you compute your SEs?

Thank you for bringing this up. Based on your feedback it's clear that I will need to reformulate the question, which I should have done shortly.
